# When deletion button of one row is clicking the entire gridview become invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

When I clicking deletion button then corresponding row is deleted. But the remaining rows in gridview become invisibe. But it displays correctly when I click those linkbutton again
. Please help me. Code is here:

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

try
   {    SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();
        con.Open();


        GridView1.Visible = true;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select e.student_id,e.student_name,e.student_nric from student_details e join student_vs_testsession_details f on e.student_id=f.student_id where f.testsession_id='" + lb_testid.Text + "' ", con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 


        }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {


    string id =Convert.ToString (GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);


    SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM student_vs_testsession_details WHERE student_id='" + id + "'", con);
   // con1.Open();
    int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (temp != 0)
  {

      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert(' record deleted succesfully')", true);
  }
       con.Close();

       GridView1.Visible = true;

       GridView1.DataBind(); 

}
```

Comment: dont you have to rebind the grid after deletion ?

Comment: Looks like you are not setting the `DataSouce` property before you rebind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is deleting it from the Database but not from the table.(Which is the table assigned to your grid)

So in that case either you need to repopulate your datatable after deleting the row or manually delete the row from the datatable bound to the gridview

What you can do  is add

**LinkButton2_Click(null,null)**  after **GridView1.Visible = true;** in deleting function

or rewrite the Dataset Function.

But dont forget ,everytime you need to assign your table  to your gridview

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Data Source of the Grid view is missing

```
Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
```

Add this as data source is required to rebind it.